# Getting MultiChoice column value without unnecessary Symbols like ";#" from sharepoint library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, radgrid

I am using Rad grid to display sharepoint library items. When i am displaying ChoiceWith CheckBox type columns, then the values are coming with additional symbols of ;# before and after each choice value.

How can i remove the ;# symbols from ChoiceWithCheckBox type columns ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's how SharePoint stores the values internally. It's basically a key/value pair.
You can manually parse the items to only return the value without the key.

Comment: Hi Wout,    Do you have an idea how to parse the items to only return the value without the key using c#. ?

Answer (score 1):

A Lookup field/column in a SharePoint list is stored as a key#value pair internally.

Use [SPFieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.aspx)  to get either the value(Text) or the key(number) from the lookup field.

SPFieldLookupValue('column name').LookupValue gives you the VALUE in the key#value pair
SPFieldLookupValue('column name').LookupId gives you the KEY in the key#value pair

I guess you are directly binding the SPItemCollections object (List.items or CAML query results) to your telerik radGrid. I usually create a generic list(in memory object), populate the list with items in the format user wants to see and then bind the generic list to radGrid.

If you are working on a SharePoint 2010 list, see if [SPRadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/moss-configuring_spradgrid_web_part.html)  telerik webpart suits your need